# Qt Creator does not recognize the my change in the pro. file

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

When I include something in Qt Creator, later I find out that that include does not exist, I want to correct that mistake by using a right path, or just deleting the include. But, that did not work, even if I delete the wrong include, but Qt Creator still try to find that include in the next build/run. I have already try to rebuild/clean the project but that does not work either. The only solution was to create a new project, or place the included file in that "wrong" place. I thought this question should not be a difficult one. But I fail to solve it.

for example, this is my pro. file.

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = simpleStitch
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

INCLUDEPATH += C:\opencv249\build\includes

LIBS += C:\opencv249\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_core249.lib
LIBS += C:\opencv249\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_highgui249.lib
LIBS += C:\opencv249\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_features2d249.lib
LIBS += C:\opencv249\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_imgproc249.lib
LIBS += C:\opencv249\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_stitcher249.lib
LIBS += C:\opencv249\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_calib3d249.lib
LIBS += C:\opencv249\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_nonfree249.lib
```

I have make a mistake in the     LIBS += C:\opencv249\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_stitcher249.lib. 
the right one should be stitching249.lib.
after I correct it to be stitching249.lib. the qt still try to find the C:\opencv249\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_stitcher249.lib. it is pretty strange. qt does not recognize my change in the pro. file even if I use the clean/ rebuild.

Comment: Please give more information about your problem. What about your settings? Tools>Option>Build&Run is your QT version correctly setted? Did you include dependency path in your .pro file ?

Comment: The problem is not how to satisfy the dependency, I have already delete all the dependency in the main.cpp file, but qt still try to find the non-existing files.

Comment: what about .pro file ?

Comment: When you have error including headers in Qt, it means your project file is not properly configured. For example, if you do not add **Qt += QtWidgets** to your project file in Qt5, you would not be able to use classes/headers like **QWidgets, QPushButton**, just to name a few.
My suggestion: Learn thoroughly how to customize your Qt Project file, it's usually the *bottleneck* for most beginners

Comment: I have add my pro. file on it.  I use qt 5.3.1 and qt creator 3.1.2.

Comment: @IchingChang Please see my last edit for windows..

Comment: you might need to run qmake again: right click on the project -> qmake

Comment: @user2859193 thanks!, you have solved my problem! Why the qt creator does not run the qmake every time I rebuild?

Comment: I don't know but sometimes it works. I always run qmake after changes to the Project file, just to be sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run qmake? if you make changes to the .pro file then you need to qmake again or it will just be building against whatever is there from your last qmake

Answer (score -1):

Please give more information, so that we can understand specific problem. Here is what you need to do before starting a new project.

To add kits, select **Tools > Options > Build & Run > Kits > Add.**

Each kit consists of a set of values that define one environment, such as a device, compiler, and Qt version. If you know you have installed a Qt version, but it is not listed in **Tools > Options > Build & Run > Qt Versions**, you must add it.

Also check that your compiler is listed in **Tools > Options > Build & Run > Compilers.**

And also you should modify your .pro file in order to your settings. Here is one of my project's .pro file. You can modified it yourself...

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = myTarget
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui


INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv

LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib \
-lopencv_core \
-lopencv_imgproc \
-lopencv_highgui \
-lopencv_ml \
-lopencv_video \
-lopencv_features2d \
-lopencv_calib3d \
-lopencv_objdetect \
-lopencv_contrib \
-lopencv_legacy \
-lopencv_flann
```

Then, in your code you need to include which libraries you want to use.. Such as:

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
```

I have never used Windows. As I know in windows symbol \ occurs problem if you not use 2 of them. Here is an example to understand clearly..

```
   INCLUDEPATH += D:\\ProgrammingTools\\opencv\\build\\include

CONFIG( debug, debug|release ) {
LIBS += -LD:\\ProgrammingTools\\opencv\\build\\x86\\vc10\\lib\
    -lopencv_core246d\
    -lopencv_highgui246d\
    -lopencv_imgproc246d\
    -lopencv_features2d246d\
}
else {
LIBS += -LD:\\ProgrammingTools\\opencv\\build\\x86\\vc10\\lib\
    -lopencv_core246\
    -lopencv_highgui246\
    -lopencv_imgproc246\
    -lopencv_features2d246\
}
```